# Extention for crash compiling by the rules in C# solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am looking for some VS2012 extension or another solution of the following problem:

1. I want to check that the my C# custom attribute was set to a Public
   class.
2. If it is not, then raise an error compiling the project.

I would like to see this test took place in the studio and has been associated with the compilation. 
And yes, I know it can be done, for example test using Ndepend or make runtime check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not something you can do with the out-of-the-box compiler. You could write an fxcop rule for it, or use a tool like (as you say) NDepend. Or possibly Roslyn when it is released. But this simply isn't something you can do "vanilla".

Frankly, I would say the easiest way to add a check for this would be in your test suite: just use reflection over all types in your key assemblies to check that it is targeted at types that satisfy your custom rules.

Comment: "You could write an fxcop rule for it". Didn't know FxCop supported this. Do you have a handy link?

Comment: @DavidArno it has been a while since I tried writing a custom fxcop rule - but it *feels* like simply overriding `BaseIntrospectionRule` / `Check` should suffice - I haven't tried applying it to exactly this scenario, though. It is entirely possible that I'm wrong, too.

Comment: *psst, interesting question you might have insight on [over here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495318)*