# xml.LoadData Data at root level is invalid, line 1, pos 1. Existing solutions not helping

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, wcf

I am trying to save an xml file that I have built from a string to local memory in App_Data of a C# web service application. I am getting this error despite looking at previous stack solutions:

Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

The xml I am trying to save to a file is a simple list of nodes.

This is being tested through a ASP.NET application on a localhost. (could this potentially affect the web service application? I see no way for this to be possible though)

I have tried implementing the solutions from these two previous stack questions:

1. [First one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17795167/xml-loaddata-data-at-the-root-level-is-invalid-line-1-position-1)
2. [Second One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495318/startswith-change-in-windows-server-2012/19495964#19495964)

Here is the first code I tried

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
var xmlWithEscapedCharacters = SecurityElement.Escape(finalXML); //finalXML is of type string

string _byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
if((xmlWithEscapedCharacters.StartsWith(_byteOrderMarkUtf8))
{
    var lastIndexOfUtf8 = _byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length - 1;
    xmlWithEscapedCharacters = xmlWithEscapedCharacters.Remove(0, lastIndexOfUtf8);
}

doc.LoadXml(xmlWithEscapedCharacters);
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.Save("Parks.xml");
```

Then I tried this from the second solution

```
string _byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
if(xmlWithEscapedCharacters[0] == '\ufeff')
{
    var lastIndexOfUtf8 = _byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length - 1;
    xmlWithEscapedCharacters = xmlWithEscapedCharacters.Remove(0, lastIndexOfUtf8);
}
```

Then I even thought there could somehow be more than one BOM at the beginning of the file and tried

```
string _byteOrderMarkUtf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetPreamble());
while (xmlWithEscapedCharacters[0] == '\ufeff')
{
    var lastIndexOfUtf8 = _byteOrderMarkUtf8.Length - 1;
    xmlWithEscapedCharacters = xmlWithEscapedCharacters.Remove(0, lastIndexOfUtf8);
}
```

Which resulted in a time out error.

I am at a loss for what feels like a rather simple issue.

EDIT 2 (Wrong XML file, sorry):
Here is an example of a valid XML file. I am adding a node with this code.

```
<Books>
<Book Cover="Paper back">
    <ISBN>978-0132309981</ISBN>
    <Title>Operating Systems Internals and Design Principles</Title>
    <Author>
        <Name>
            <First>William</First>
            <Last>Stallings</Last>
        </Name>
        <Contact Office="BY101">
            <Phone>480-965-0000</Phone>
        </Contact>
    </Author>
    <Publisher>Prentice Hall</Publisher>
    <Year Edition="7">2011</Year>
</Book>
</Books>
```

Comment: Can we have an example value for `xmlWithEscapedCharacters`? Please directly copy/paste directly into the post, do not paste it via any other application.

Comment: Why are you subtracting `- 1`

Comment: I am subtracting -1 to get the index.

Comment: xmlWithEscapedCharacters should simply be finalXml with any reserved characters mutated into the escape sequences. When testing the code without doing this step (replacing all instances of xmlWithEscapedCharacters with finalXml) the result is the same. I will add an example of the xml to the post.

Comment: Why are you calling `SecurityElement.Escape` before trying to load the xml? It will replace xml characters such as < with &lt; - which will cause `xmlDocument.LoadXml` to fail

Comment: So the XML above is before calling `SecurityElement.Escape` or after?

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question to include the full `ToString()` output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Data at root level is invalid, line 1, pos 1**" is usually caused by
1.XML files are not encoded in UTF-8
2.The XML file has BOM characters.

I think you can check if there have BOM characters after replacing invalid characters with valid characters using the **SecurityElement.Escape(String)** method.

```
 public string UTF8Str(string str)
        {
           
            byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(str);
         
            byte[] bomBuffer = { 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf };
            if ((buffer[0] == bomBuffer[0])&& (buffer[1] == bomBuffer[1])&&(buffer[2] == bomBuffer[2]))

            { 
                var result = new UTF8Encoding(false).GetString(buffer);
                result = "<" + result.Substring(result.IndexOf('<') + 1);
                return result;
            }
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        })
```

Comment: When calling `SecurityElement.Escape` on the xml string, the first character of the first line will be `&` as the document starts with an escaped element `&lt;Books&gt;` - this will never work regardless of encoding and BOMs